# Group by two fields & sum fields from embedded documents MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use the aggregate function to group documents by two fields, sum a value in an embedded document and finally find the highest and lowest value.

Group by Company & Date.

Sum stock volume.

Highest & lowest stock price.

Count the documents per Company & Date.

The document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f889026fa83f52985807c7a"),
  "Date": "2019-09-26",
  "Time": "13:30:00",
  "Stock": {
    "open": 1733.256,
    "high": 1743.9292,
    "low": 1733.1847,
    "close": 1740.0262,
    "volume": 330114
  },
  "Company": "Amazon"
}
```

So far I tried this but it didn't work:

```
db.stocks.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      "Company": "$Company",
      "Date": "$Date"
    },
    "volumeSum": {
      $sum: "$Stock.volume"
    },
    "maxPrice": {
      $max: "$Stock}, "
      minPrice ":{$min:"
      Stock "},"
      Count ":{$count:1}
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
db.stocks.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "Company": "$Company",
        "Date": "$Date"
      },
      "volumeSum": {
        $sum: "$Stock.volume"
      },
      "maxPrice": {
        $max: "$Stock.high"
      },
      "minPrice": {
        $min: "$Stock.low"
      },
      "Count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sq9fmIybbA7)